# Mobile Cloud Computing simulation using NS2

Tags: networking, mobile, cloud, google-cloud-storage, ns2

Can I have the basic simulation on Mobile Cloud Gaming using N2 simulator? I am working on Cloud Mobile Gaming and could not find any similar simulation coding in NS2 to help me to guide on my work.

Answer (score 0):

[Green Cloud Simulator](http://greencloud.gforge.uni.lu/) is based on NS2. There are other good and powerful tools like [OMNEST](http://www.omnest.com/), [ns-3](https://www.nsnam.org/). See, if these work for you.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Khalid for the information. I would like to try Green Cloud Simulator. Can it be used to create a Mobile Cloud Gaming?